# How to add prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application or Setup Project

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, installation, prerequisites

I've included .NET 4.5 as a prerequisite but when I have built the setup project, I got an error message saying:

> Error 1   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine.

The http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883 page instructs users to place the prerequisite installers in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0a\Bootstrapper\Packages`. I'm using Windows 8 and there is no directory named `Microsoft SDKs`. Where else can I place the prerequisites or is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the SDK solved the problem.